# C# Grid View Airport Screen Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a simple page on web forms, showing a grid view which source is sql server. So far so good, the grid view shows the 50 rows/records that i have on my database.However we are changing the information of those rows very often and also adding and deleting rows. What i need is a timer in order to refresh the page every 1 minute.The challenge for me is to have an automatic paging every 1 minute so the grid view only shows 10 rows each time and after one minute shows the next 10 rows. Ss soon as it reach the last set, it starts from page 1 again and so on.

Comment: you should show your code, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's an example of an [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx)

Comment: Along with Rick S you will need to have a timer control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks a lot for you help.You are awesome, let me work on it. mcNets i am sorry about the code i will publish it in a moment.